# Want Python code for negative and positive digit representation of integers

Tags: python

We consider two type of digits, negative and positive to represent integers in given base.

Let n=1997 so, it is equal to 2000-3= 2×10³+0×10²+0×10+(-3)×1=(2,0,0,-3) and order of positive and negative places are (...+,+,-) similarly it is equal to (2,0,-1,7) order is(...,+,+,-,+),(2,0,-0,-3) order is(...,+,+,-,-),(2,-0,0,-3) order is(...,+,-,+,-),(2,-1,9,7) order is(...,+,-,+,+),(1,-8,-1,9,7)order is(...,+,-,-,+,+)

If we consider digits, $-0$ and $0$ are as distinct digits but its value are same and equal to zero, then any integer can written uniquely with negative and positive digits with its preserve order of negative positive position respectively.

*PROBLEM* : let (...,+,+,-) preserve order of positive and negative digits, i.e. only fist digit from right should be negative, for example, 23=(3,-7). How to write the python program for this conversion of integer to such given Order of negative postive places representation system?

(Edit: Question) what will code for any given arrangements for preserve order?

I have attempted following, but it not give correct output for single digit number and for number whose leading digit is 9 which again mention at the end as a error. Can you please give better code to get correct output for all integer.

```
def D1(num,n2):
    if num == 1:
        return 1
    if num == 0:
        return 0
    rem_array = [0]*3
    le1 = len(str(n2))
    while n2 != 0:
        le = len(str(n2))
        le2 = le1-le
        mod = n2%num
        if mod != 0 and le2 != 0:
            rem = mod
            n2 = n2 - rem
            rem_array[le2]=rem
            n2 = n2//num
        elif mod != 0 and n2 != 1:
            rem = num - mod
            n2 = n2 + rem
            rem_array[le2]=-rem
            n2 = n2//num
        else:
            n2 = n2//num
            rem_array[le2]=0
    return rem_array[::-1]


for i in range(3,128,13):
    print(i,D1(10,i))


output
3 [0, 0, 0]
16 [0, 2, -4]
29 [0, 3, -1]
42 [0, 5, -8]
55 [0, 6, -5]
68 [0, 7, -2]
81 [0, 9, -9]
94 [0, 1, 0]
107 [1, 1, -3]
120 [1, 2, 0]
```

Error : for 3 and 94 output is not correct.

Comment: are you always using numbers less than 1000?

Comment: @JonSG no, i use 3 digit number this to examine first error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to consider carry here.  You just need to pull off one digit at a time, and in the case of the first digit, if it was not zero, then add the base in to compensate for the subtraction:

```
def D1(base,val):
    if base < 2:
        return base
    digits = []
    digit = val % base
    if digit:
        # Subtract the base from the first digit.
        digits.append( digit-base )
        # Add it in to our number as a carry/borrow.
        val += base
    else:
        digits.append( 0 )
    val //= base
    while val:
        digits.append( val % base )
        val //= base
    return digits[::-1]

for i in range(3,128,13):
    print(i,D1(10,i))
```

Output:

```
3 [1, -7]
16 [2, -4]
29 [3, -1]
42 [5, -8]
55 [6, -5]
68 [7, -2]
81 [9, -9]
94 [1, 0, -6]
107 [1, 1, -3]
120 [1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it gives output for arrangement of oder (...,+,+,-). can you please give mi code for general , if any given arrangement of order we have.

Comment: No, I'm not going to do your homework for you, but you can do it.  You can see there are two section in there: one that handles "-", one that handles "+".  You just need to rearrange the code.